# Default Implementation of JWT

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I'm creating an app which uses OAuth for third party authentication.  I would like to use this with JWT but the solution I'm using is faulty and I would perfer a more standarized way.

I have a startup configuration which uses OAuth to login and as my authentication schema:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        cfg.SaveToken = true;

        cfg.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
    })
    .AddCoinbase(options => {
        options.SendLimitCurrency = "USD";
        options.ClientId = Configuration["Coinbase:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Coinbase:ClientSecret"];
        COINBASE_SCOPES.ForEach(scope => options.Scope.Add(scope));
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:coinbase:avatar", "avatar_url");
    });
```

When a user logs in they go through the default challenge logic in the Account controller.

```
[HttpPost("ExternalLogin")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
{
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback), "Account", new { returnUrl });
    var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
    return Challenge(properties, provider);
}
```

In my external login it quite annoying to have to generate my own tokens I would perfer this to be done by some default logic. **Note** some logic is omitted for simplicity

```
[HttpGet("ExternalLoginCallback")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
{
    var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);

    var user = await (result.Succeeded ?
         _userManager.FindByLoginAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey)
        : this.CreateIdentityUser(info));

    var jwt = await Tokens.GenerateJwt(_jwtFactory.GenerateClaimsIdentity(user.UserName, user.Id),
            _jwtFactory, _jwtOptions);
```

I've found a jwtfactory to create tokens online like so:

```
public class JwtFactory : IJwtFactory
{
    //... More Code
    public async Task<string> GenerateEncodedToken(string userName, ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        var claims = new[]
        {
             new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userName),
             new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, await _jwtOptions.JtiGenerator()),
             new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, ToUnixEpochDate(_jwtOptions.IssuedAt).ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64),
             identity.FindFirst(Constants.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol),
             identity.FindFirst(Constants.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Id)
         };

        // Create the JWT security token and encode it.
        var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: _jwtOptions.Issuer,
            audience: _jwtOptions.Audience,
            claims: claims,
            notBefore: _jwtOptions.NotBefore,
            expires: _jwtOptions.Expiration,
            signingCredentials: _jwtOptions.SigningCredentials);

        var encodedJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);

        return encodedJwt;
    }

    public ClaimsIdentity GenerateClaimsIdentity(string userName, string id)
    {
        return new ClaimsIdentity(new GenericIdentity(userName, "Token"), new[]
        {
            new Claim(Constants.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Id, id),
            new Claim(Constants.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, Constants.JwtClaims.ApiAccess)
        });
    }
    //... More code
}

public class Tokens
{
    public static async Task<string> GenerateJwt(ClaimsIdentity identity, IJwtFactory jwtFactory, 
        JwtIssuerOptions jwtOptions, JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = null)
    {
        serializerSettings = serializerSettings ?? new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };

        var id = identity.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "id").Value;
        var response = new
        {
            id = id,
            auth_token = await jwtFactory.GenerateEncodedToken(id, identity),
            expires_in = (int)jwtOptions.ValidFor.TotalSeconds
        };

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, serializerSettings);
    }
}
```

This JWTFactory seems like that logic could be made universal,  I'm wondering if there is a more .net stardarized way to do this e.g something

```
services.AddSingleton<ITokenGenerator>(sp => {

    var claimsMap = new ClaimsMap();
    claimsMap.AddFromIdentity(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, x => x.UserName);
    var tokenGenerator = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JWT.TokenGenerator(claimsMap);
});
```

Basically I'm looking for a more standarized light weight way to handle JWT Token Generation.  I don't need anything too crazy like IdentityServer (I don't need to handle multiple client).

Comment: could you re-word this - i'm finding it hard to understand: `This JWTFactory doesn't seems to have an logic that couldnt be made universal`.   Would it help also to define `faulty`?

Comment: No, there's not a single JWT implementation in ASP.NET Core -- you have to roll your own

Comment: @JohnB I've reworded basically it looks like the Factory isn't doing anything that would be custom to my application

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks for the response  I didn't want to have to write and support that in my application but it looks like I have to.  If you post that as an answer I'll mark it correct

Comment: this might help: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Does that mean I'll have to implement my own expiration validation or is that handled by the AddJWTBearer?

Comment: @JohnB Thanks, I have a token Generator which sortof works,  I just hate having to support all of this extra code when it seems like something that should be baked into .net-core